# perl insert a string into a file AFTER a regex is matched

Tags: perl

So I get this output from a sybase database output. 
I need to take out the double quotes and insert some row definitions to the tables. I gues perl is the tool to do it

```
 "NO Comm","-"
"INVESTMENT","29541","3860237","0","ANEW","(null)","BP    ","frantzla","A"
"DERIVS","110000","2875587","0","ANEW","0","BP    ","frantzla","A"
"DERIVS","4089","1185810","0","IBKD","0","BP    ","unsalr  ","A"
"COMMERCE","705","41185","0","ANEW","(null)","BP    ","madiganj","A"
"FIRST","504","236","0","ANEW","0","CPS   ","kilkenki","A"
" ","-"
"Opera Pending","-"
"FIRST","827921","23565575","20699","ANEW","2.5","CPS   ","kilkenki","A"
"INC","218780","3596112","5472","ANEW","2.5","CPS   ","madiganj","A"
" ","-"
"ETC Pending","-"
"BANK , PITTSBURGH","251508","10803056","1258","IBKD","0.5","CPS   ","dennyad ","A"
"SYDNEY","4500","178173","45","IBKD","1","CPS   ","dennyad ","A"
" ","-"
"Confirmed Booking","-"
"MOTHER FUND","22400","1187584","1781","IBKD","15","BP    ","crouzejo","A"
"ASSET MANAGEMENT, SGIIC, S.","45010","614834","922","IBKD","15","BP    ","ruizdemi","A"
```

Once I take the "double quotes" I come up with some table names that all end up with a ",-" right after them.
I need to put a header after the talbe names to defien the rows. So pretty much all all I have to do is evervy time the
perl script hits a "\w+\,-" all it need to do is insert this line into the next line.

```
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
```

It is the header for the values below it.
    It prints out the header - but not the whole report.
    This is a CSV file, and I need to put these headers over the tables.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fhIn,  '<', 'today.txt'          or die $!;
my $add_trip = "Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis" ;
while (<$fhIn>) {
   my $print_flag = 0 ;
   tr/\"//d;
   if(/\w+\,-/) {
       $print_flag = 1 ;
           if($print_flag) {
           print "$add_trip\n" ;
       } else { print $_ ;  }
   }
}
```

result - the tables are not printed only the lines I want to insert are printed:

```
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
```

I need something more like this:

```
ETC Pending,-
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
BANK , PITTSBURGH,251508,10803056,1258,IBKD,0.5,CPS   ,dennyad ,A
SYDNEY,4500,178173,45,IBKD,1,CPS   ,dennyad ,A
 ,-
Confirmed Booking,-
Client , Shares , Notional, TotalComm, Status, Comm, CommType, Owner, TradingBasis
MOTHER FUND,22400,1187584,1781,IBKD,15,BP    ,crouzejo,A
ASSET MANAGEMENT, SGIIC, S.,45010,614834,922,IBKD,15,BP    ,ruizdemi,A
```

bonus - it would be great to get rid of the ',-' after the script is all done - it would be greeat to get rid of them from the csv file , but I need them to put int he headers, so I cannot get rid of them until I know that the headers for the tables are in .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things first:

- Since this is a CSV file, it is probably safest to use a CSV parsing module such as [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)
- Since you are matching `,-` with a regex, you should be sure that none of your fields happen to contain that string

That being said, try replacing this:

```
if(/\w+\,-/) {
    $print_flag = 1 ;
        if($print_flag) {
        print "$add_trip\n" ;
    } else { print $_ ;  }
}
```

with this:

```
if(/\w+\,-/) {
    print "$add_trip\n";
} else {
    print;
}
```

If we reformat the way you had it, it is easier to see the problem:

```
if(/\w+\,-/) {
    $print_flag = 1 ;
    if($print_flag) {
        print "$add_trip\n";
    } else {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

If `/\w+\,-/` didn't match, nothing would happen, since your `print $_` was in an `else` statement one level too deep. Also, there is no need to set `$print_flag = 1` unless you use it elsewhere in the code. Even if you do, there is no need for the `if($print_flag)`, since you just set `$print_flag = 1` in the previous line.

**Alternative:**

It isn't totally clear to me exactly what you want your output to be, but if the above isn't it, this might be:

```
if(/\w+\,-/) {
    s/,-//;
    print "$_$add_trip\n";
} else {
    print;
}
```

This will check for the `,-` and if it finds it will remove it, print that line, then print `$add_trip`. If `,-` is not found, it will just print the line.